# How to correctly display registration form in symfony 2.6?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, formbuilder

I'm am new to Symfony 2 framework and i'm trying, without success, to create a registration form to add users to my db.

I followed this [tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html) and everything seems to work fine, except that my form won't show up.

This is my UserType.php class:

```
class UserType extends  AbstractType{



public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    echo "builder";
    $builder->add('user', 'user_form');
    $builder->add('password', 'repeated', array(
        'first_name'  => 'password',
        'second_name' => 'confirm',
        'type'        => 'password',
    ));

}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'XXX\Entity\User'
    ));
}
```

RegistrationType.php:

```
class RegistrationType extends  AbstractType{


public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    echo "1";
    $userType=new UserType();
    $builder->add('user', $userType);
    echo "2";
    $builder->add('Aggiungi', 'submit');
    echo "3";
}

/**
 * Returns the name of this type.
 *
 * @return string The name of this type
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'register_form';
}
```

}

And my AccountControllorer.php :

```
    class AccountController extends Controller
{
    public function registerAction()
    {
        $registration = new Registration();
        $form = $this->createForm(new RegistrationType(), $registration, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('account_create'),
        ));

        return $this->render(
            'xxx:Account:register.html.twig',
            array('form' => $form->createView())
        );
    }

    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            echo "controller 1 ok";
        $rt=new RegistrationType();
        $r=new Registration();
        $form = $this->createForm($rt, $r);
        echo "controller 2 ok";
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        echo "all ok";
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $registration = $form->getData();

            $em->persist($registration->getUser());
            $em->flush();
           echo "yess";
        }

        return $this->render(
            'xxx:Account:register.html.twig',
            array('form' => $form->createView())
        );
    }
}
```

After some echoes in the code, i've found that the controller stops after "controller 1 ok" (i.e. the form is't created), so I echoed more in deep, and i've found that method builForm in UserType goes in a loop, it echoes "builder" infinite times, giving 500 internal Error in browser.

So, where is the problem? I'm stuck here from all the day. If you want more code snippet just ask!

Thanks in advance,
Panc

Comment: I don't understand this: 
    $builder->add('user', 'user_form'); ?

Comment: uh, what a good question... Honestly, I am not sure that is for the fact that when i added this in my services.php file: 
$userFormDefinition=new Definition('xxx\Form\Type\UserType');
$userFormDefinition->addTag('form.type');
$container->setDefinition('user_form',$userFormDefinition);

but I'm am really really confused aobut this part, sorry...

Comment: Ok that seems to be a good explaination but it should be in Registration type and not in UserType, like this you include user into user... That explains the loop ?

Comment: oh, I think that can be a possible solution! I'll try it later, thank you!